# The App is not open in Windows by sending the command through SSH connection from the virtual Linux

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, ssh

I have a system in which there is Windows OS and a virtual environment, including Ubuntu. I installed OpenSSH on the Windows OS, then configured it to establish an SSH connection between the virtual Ubuntu and the Windows. I can connect to Windows through SSH in the Ubuntu terminal, and I can even create new text files. However, I need to open an exe on Windows by sending the command from Ubuntu. After establishing the SSH connection and changing the directory to the my_app.exe directory using the cd command in Ubuntu, I typed the my_app.exe and hit the enter key, but nothing happened on Windows and the my_app.exe did not execute.

Comment: In Ubuntu, in Ubuntu File Explorer, try:   SMB://192.168.x.y/windowsfolder  .   Authenticate and see if you can run the App that way. I have mapped drives this way.

Comment: @John Shall I install the Samba for doing that? Consider I need to execute the app on Windows side.

Comment: If you start with Ubuntu to map the folder, the Samba is not required. I know about Samba, but the above is easier

Comment: @John If I understood correctly, in the way you proposed there is no need to establish ssh connection. I just need to share the corresponding folder on the Windows side and use the commands above-mentioned on the Linux side to map the folder.

Comment: If you are on the same LAN, there is no need for SSH.  Just map the folder. I do this regularly.

Comment: @John
I'm asking again just for clarification. I need to open an app on the "Windows side," not on the Linux side, just by sending a command from the Ubuntu SSH client to the Windows SSH server, and you told me that this process can be done by mapping if the server and the client are on the same local network. Am I correct?